# How to get new error log occurrences in last 7 days in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

After deployment, we monitor the logs to detect any new error occurrences. I'm seeking a mechanism or approach to identify these new errors.

For example, if an issue arises after deployment and the log displays an error like "XYZ field not found," I want to identify all unique errors that have occurred today as a result of new code changes.

Thanks a lot for helping in advance.

Comment: There is not enough information to give an answer. Please elaborate the question, give sample data, give an example about the expected results and any more information so that we can help you.

Comment: @MusabDogan I added example what I am trying to achieve please let me know if that helps

Comment: Please elaborate more. Do you want to identify this errors with a DSL query or a kibana dashboard?

Comment: anything is fine with me

Comment: Sorry I can't help you if you can't willing to answer my questions. The information you provided is not enough. Im trying to help you but forcing you to give some information :) Please read my first comment again if you need help and provide all the information I want.